# Confluent MySQL connector connection not established

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-cloud

I am trying to connect MySQL DB (installed in my laptop) from Confluent Cloud Remote access using MySQL Source connector. I am not able to establish the connection with MySQL Connector.

> Error: Unable to validate configuration. If an update was made to the
> configuration, this means that the configuration was invalid, and the
> connector continues to operate on a previous configuration that passed
> validation. Errors:
> connection.password: Could not connect to database
> table.whitelist: Unable to check whether table(s) exist due to connection error

The same JDBC connection works via a Java program on my laptop.

Sample program I used:

```
try {
    // connect way #1
    String url1 = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.2**.**:3306/test_kafka_connectors";
    String user = "Adhi";
    String password = "*****";

    conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(url1, user, password);
    if (conn1 != null) {
        System.out.println("Connected to the database test1");
    }
```

The hostname (localhost with port 3306 or 192.168.2**.**:3306 (my laptop IP address) works fine in the Java program.

With Confluent connector, I am not able to establish the connection.
Steps which I have done below

Step 1. I have added the connection string details and username and password inside the connector.

Authentication
Connection host\
192.168.2**.2**
Connection port
3306
Connection user
Adhi
Connection password
****************
Database name
test_kafka_connectors
SSL mode
prefer

Step 2. Created the user (Adhi with IP address of Confluent) and granted the permission in MySQL below. Please refer db user image.

[image]

Step 3: I tried to place the bind address property of Confluent IP address in MySQL conf file mysqlrouter.conf and restarted the mysql service, but still the Connector connection is not working.

Comment: Bind addresses are for the server, not defining "what is allowed to connect, externally". You should bind to `0.0.0.0` to allow all connections.

Answer (score 0):

`192.168.2**.2**` is your LAN subnet within your home network. You need to use your public IP, provided by your ISP. You also need to port-forward 3306 through your router.

---

Unclear why you "need" Confluent Cloud. You should be able to run Kafka Connect JDBC connector (and Kafka) on your local machine along with MySQL.

Comment: #oneCricketeer , I installed Confluent Kafka in my local and tried to connect MySQL using JDBC connector, i could not see the connection success in Confluent center. It is failed and there is no message displayed in Confluent control Center UI page for the JDBC connector. I am able to connect MySQL DB via Java JDBC program with same connection string.

Comment: I personally do not use Control Center, so cannot help with that. You don't need Confluent Platform, only the JDBC connector and Apache Kafka (there's no such thing as Confluent Kafka)